# Trouble configuring JBoss Management Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jboss

[image: Configuration of JBoss Management plugin.]

Hi

I tried configuring JBoss Management Plugin for Jenkins with above details. But when i use it in my job it gives me following error. Any inputs?

**Error Log**

```
SHUTDOWN: Checking if server is running (max 20 seconds)...
FATAL: TRACE
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerPlugin.isTraceEnabled(Log4jLoggerPlugin.java:85)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.isTraceEnabled(Logger.java:122)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1310)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1548)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:634)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at hudson.plugins.jboss.JMXUtils.getMBeanServer(JMXUtils.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.jboss.JMXUtils.checkServerStatus(JMXUtils.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.jboss.JBossBuilder.perform(JBossBuilder.java:106)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Error Ends here**

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the jenkins version you are using older version of log4j ( possibly 1.2.9) upgrading to the newer version (1.2.14) would solve the problem. There is a bug here https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4433.

For quick resolution: goto  jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib in your filesytem  and replace log4j.jar the newer version of it. ( 1.2.14 ) worked for me.