# Nohup didn't work in Jenkins shell

Tags: shell, jenkins, jboss, nohup

I want my JBoss server to run in background, for that I am using ***nohup ./startPID.sh > /dev/null 2>&1&*** command. But when I pass same command in Jenkins, it doesn't work as expected. The console output in Jenkins says "command ran successfully" but in backend the JBoss server is still down.
Any inputs?

Regards
Manish Mehra

Answer (score 1):

Use "at now" instead of "nohup"

In your job jenkins (execute shell) put :

```
set +e #so "at now" will run even if java -jar fails
#Run java app in background
echo "java -jar $(ls | grep *.jar | head -n 1)" | at now + 1 min
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [JBoss management plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JBoss+Management+Plugin)

which spins up JBoss for you

> This plugin allows to manage a JBoss Application Server during build
> procedure.
>
> With the plugin we can start/stop JBoss AS. It's very useful if we
> need to run some integration tests against of the server. There is
> also operation allows verification if artifacts are deployable.

It looks to be quite an old plugin but has cuurent users

Comment: Thanks KCACO. I have already tried using this plugin. Looks like it needs JBoss to be running as service. I am not sure though. I raised a query for that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109287/trouble-configuring-jboss-management-plugin-for-jenkins). Got no response there as well.